# WinUI 3 nested resource dictionaries?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

Are nested multilevel dictionaries possible? Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Button1">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackground" Color="HotPink" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundDisabled" Color="HotPink" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPressed" Color="HotPink" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver" Color="HotPink" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForeground" Color="White" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForegroundPointerOver" Color="White" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderBrush" Color="White" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver" Color="White" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderBrushFocused" Color="White" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderBrushPressed" Color="White" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        
    </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Is it possible to access `Button1` dictionary somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `Button1` with the `ThemeDictionaries`. You could try to edit Button1's <Button.Resources>.

```
   <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click"  >

        <Button.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                        
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackground" Color="HotPink" />
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundDisabled" Color="HotPink" />
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPressed" Color="HotPink" />
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver" Color="HotPink" />
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForeground" Color="White" />
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForegroundPointerOver" Color="White" />
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderBrush" Color="White" />
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver" Color="White" />
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderBrushFocused" Color="White" />
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderBrushPressed" Color="White" />
                        
                    </ResourceDictionary>

                </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Button.Resources>

        Click Me </Button>
```

If you want to use the same `ThemeDictionaries` across all buttons in the app, you could put the ResourceDictionary inside the `Application.Resources` in the `App.xaml` file.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, I need to use it across the App, code should be reusable. And also I need every color set of button has variants for light and dark themes. Button -> Primary (Blue) -> Light, Button -> Primary (Blue) -> Dark, and so on... Also in "color set" I mean not only background color, but also foreground, disabled, focus, mouse over, click states. So in this case we can't do it with just only using Style, that's why I'm considering about it and asking.

Comment: If you need to use it across the App, you could put the `ResourceDictionary` inside the `Application.Resources` in the `App.xaml` file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you don't want to apply custom `ThemeDictionaries` to all your Buttons. You can do this with a help of this `AttachedProperty`:

```cs
public class ResourcesServices
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResourcesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Resources",
            typeof(ResourceDictionary),
            typeof(ResourcesServices),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ResourceDictionary), OnResourcesPropertyChanged));

    public static ResourceDictionary GetResources(DependencyObject obj) => (ResourceDictionary)obj.GetValue(ResourcesProperty);

    public static void SetResources(DependencyObject obj, ResourceDictionary value) => obj.SetValue(ResourcesProperty, value);

    private static void OnResourcesPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is not FrameworkElement source ||
            e.NewValue is not ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary)
        {
            return;
        }

        ResourceDictionaryCloner.Clone(resourceDictionary, source.Resources);
    }
}

public static class ResourceDictionaryCloner
{
    public static ResourceDictionary Clone(ResourceDictionary resource, ResourceDictionary destination)
    {
        if (resource is null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (resource.Source is not null)
        {
            destination.Source = resource.Source;
            return destination;
        }

        if (resource.ThemeDictionaries is not null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> theme in resource.ThemeDictionaries)
            {
                if (theme.Value is ResourceDictionary themedResource)
                {
                    ResourceDictionary themeDictionary = new();
                    Clone(themedResource, themeDictionary);
                    destination.ThemeDictionaries[theme.Key] = themeDictionary;
                    continue;
                }

                destination.ThemeDictionaries[theme.Key] = theme.Value;
            }
        }

        if (resource.MergedDictionaries is not null)
        {
            foreach (ResourceDictionary mergedResource in resource.MergedDictionaries)
            {
                ResourceDictionary themeDictionary = new();
                Clone(mergedResource, themeDictionary);
                destination.MergedDictionaries.Add(themeDictionary);
            }
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> item in resource)
        {
            destination[item.Key] = item.Value;
        }

        return destination;
    }
}
```

Now we can set the resources in a style:

```xml
<Style
    x:Key="CustomButton"
    TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="local:ResourcesServices.Resources">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                        <SolidColorBrush
                            x:Key="ButtonBackground"
                            Color="Red" />
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                        <SolidColorBrush
                            x:Key="ButtonBackground"
                            Color="Blue" />
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So:

```xml
<Button Content="Default button" />
<Button Content="Custom button" Style={StaticResource CustomButton} />
```

THis answer is based on this great [article](https://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2021/xaml-lightweight-styling-done-right).

Comment: Did you get to solve your issue?